# Log frequency stable_baselines3

Tags: python, logging, stable-baselines

I am training a Reinforcement Learning agent using stable_baselines3.

Is there a way to edit the frequency of the logs (*log the mean reward every 200 steps*) ?

I found this parameter `_log_freq` but it's not working

```py
class TensorboardCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, verbose=0):
        super().__init__(verbose)
        self._log_freq = 100

    def _on_step(self) -> bool:
        #some code
        return True
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to include the code that you have already tried (see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the parameter `log_interval` in the learn() function

```py
model = A2C("CnnPolicy", env, verbose=1,tensorboard_log='./'+tmp_path, )
model.learn(total_timesteps=int(N_STEP),callback=TensorboardCallback(),log_interval = 100)
```